# Prevent Multiple Event Bindings on Elements Outside UpdatePanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a webform with elements both inside and out of an `UpdatePanel` that need to have javascript events bound to them. If I use `$(document).ready()` to bind events, the elements outside the `UpdatePanel` work properly, but the elements inside the `UpdatePanel` lose their bindings on postback. If I use `pageLoad()` to bind events, the elements inside the `UpdatePanel` work properly, but the elements outside end up with the same events bound to them multiple times - once for each postback that occurs. How can I get all the elements to have only a single instance of the event bound to them regardless of where they appear on the page?

Example ASPX page:

```
<%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" codebehind="Default.aspx.cs" inherits="WebApplication1.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>jQuery Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form runat="server">
            <asp:scriptmanager enablepartialrendering="true" runat="server" />

            <p><a href="#">Completely unrelated link here.</a></p>

            <asp:updatepanel id="UpdatePanelTime" updatemode="conditional" runat="server">
                <contenttemplate>
                    <p>The time was last updated: <asp:literal id="LiteralTime" text="Never" runat="server" /></p>
                    <p><asp:linkbutton id="LinkButtonUpdateTime" text="Update Time"
                                       onclick="LinkButtonUpdateTimeClick" runat="server" /></p>
                </contenttemplate>
            </asp:updatepanel>
        </form>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function pageLoad() {
                $('a').click(function () {
                    // This click event will only occur once for the <a> in the update
                    // panel, but once-per postback + 1 for the one outside of it.
                    console.log('Link "' + $(this).text() + '" was clicked.');
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Example code-behind:

```
using System;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void LinkButtonUpdateTimeClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LiteralTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use an UpdatePanel?  You could just update the particular element you wanted with a single AJAX call.

Comment: Yes, although in the sample code the UpdatePanel is pretty useless, that's not the real code. In the real code we want an UpdatePanel because it's more complicated than the example.

Comment: Well, you could use a PageMethod with jQuery to control any part of the page you need at any time you need.